# How to Type Cast null as Bool in C#?

Tags: c#, casting, boolean, nullable

I'm having one null-able bool (`bool?`) variable, it holds a value null. One more variable of type pure `bool`, I tried to convert the null-able bool to bool. But I faced an error "**Nullable object must have a value.**"

My C# Code is

```
bool? x = (bool?) null;
bool y = (bool)x;
```

Comment: Your value is `null`...it has no `bool` value to be cast to - if you'd like the default value for the type to be assigned if `x` is null, use the `GetValueOrDefault()` method.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use `x.GetValueOrDefault()` to assign default value (`false` for `System.Boolean`) to `y` in the event that `x.HasValue == false`.

Alternatively you can use the null-coalescing operator (??), like so:

```
bool y = x ?? false;
```

Comment: I'd use the alternative one primarily .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Checking for equality with a boolean constant is a convenient shortcut:

```
        var x = (bool?) null;
        var y = x == true;
```

Answer (score -1):

If I have a property boolean

```
If (HasData.HasValue) Then
            Dim value As Boolean = HasData.Value
        End If
        ' or you can also do this
        If (HasData IsNot Nothing) Then

    End If
```

That should fix your bug.

hope this helps